# Is there any automatic validation with an ASP.NET form bound to Entity DataSource?

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework

I have an entity model and forms data bound via an entity datasource.

If all the data requirements (type, length) are "known" by the model, is there an automated way to tell a form to look at the model and validate based on the data properties?

Or do I have to add a validator to every form field?

Thanks
Kevin

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing using `ASP .Net WebForms`.

However, you don't have to write each time the same markup with TextBox, RequiredFieldValidator, RegularExpressionValidator, etc because you can use `UserControls` to easy your work.

Group all these in a single user control, add to it a property which retrieves and sets `TextBox.Text` property and use it further in `DetailsView or FormView`